# How to customize zoom control position in google map iframe

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe, maps

I have embedded google map version 1 in iframe, so i do not have any JS to customize zoom control. Is there any way to change position of zoom control in iframe?

Comment: What does the code for the embedded map look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using embeded map, there is no way to customize the appearance of the controls.  If you want to do that you need to create a map using the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).  That has [documented methods for positioning the controls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls)

Comment: Okay!! Thank you, but at least can i remove those zoom buttons from embedded map?